# Edit JavaScript (Tomorrow's date)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to edit some JavaScript code which basically shows tomorrow's date. However for Friday and weekends (Friday, Saturday and Sunday) it should show the following Monday's date.

Here is the code I have:

```
var date = new Date(); //  timezone
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // move to tomorrow
date.setUTCHours(11,0,0,0); // set time using UTC(GMT) timezone
document.getElementById("next-shipment").textContent = date.toLocaleString();
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3edrtvf/)**

For example let say today is Tuesday, November 4, 2015. The javascript code should show "**November 5, 2015**"---> in this format.
On Friday, Saturday,and Sunday the code should show: Next Monday's date: **November 9, 2015**

The code should work all year around.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var today = new Date(); //  timezone
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<br/>Today's next day is: " + FormatDate(GetNextDay(today));


function GetNextDay(date){
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // move to next day.
  switch(date.getDay()) {
  case 0: //Sunday
  case 6: //Saturday
    date = GetNextDay(date);
  }
  return date;
}

function FormatDate(date){
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  return months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();
}

function TestDate(){
  var date = new Date(document.getElementById("TestDate").value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br/>Selected day's next day is: " + FormatDate(GetNextDay(date));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="TestDate" value="November 06, 2015" />
<input type="button" value="Get Next Day" onclick="TestDate();" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

The idea is fairly simple:

The first two lines and the `TestDate()` function at the end are only for testing and you don't need them in your code.

The job is mainly done by the `GetNextDay()` function. You give it a date and it calculates and give you back the next date (skipping the weekend). It does that in two steps:

1- First it adds one day to the given date `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);`.

2- It checks the day of the new date `date.getDay()`. If it is 6 or 0 (Saturday or Sunday) it calls itself again `date = GetNextDay(date);` which means it will add one more day to the date. This concept of a function calling itself is called "recursion" in programming. When it reaches Monday, it will stop calling itself and return the date.

The only way to calculate the next day properly is by adding one day to the date. This utilizes JavaScript's Date library which knows how to do the calculation. For example, it knows that adding one day to "November 30" is "December 1", NOT "November 31". If we try to do that manually by adding 1 to number of the day: 30 + 1 = 31, but "November 31" is not a valid date. To solve this issue, we will need to write a library similar to the one that JavaScript has. Obviously, this is like reinventing the wheel and there is no point in that.

Comment: Any ideas how to make it show the date as "November 5, 2015" instead of 11/6/2015, 6:00:00 AM ?
Also for On every friday, saturday and sunday the date must show  of the following Monday. By the way, my Timezone is EST (EDT)

Comment: It already does that. It shows Monday for every Friday, Saturday and Sunday. You can test it. I will update my answer to display the date in the format you want.

Comment: I've added a formatting function. You also want the local time displayed, don't you? If not, simply delete the `+ date.toLocaleTimeString()` at the end.

Comment: Right this minute, on Nov 4 2015 at 17:17 pacific time, using "Run code snippet" is showing me `Today's next day is: November 6, 201520153:00:00 AM` (wrong date - 6 instead of 5 - and formatting is run together)

Comment: @StephenP That's because the OP had this line `date.setUTCHours(11,0,0,0);` in his code. I thought he needed it so I left it there. Now after reading his comments, it seems he doesn't care about the time, so I removed it.

Comment: Thank you, the solutions also works well. I am trying to read it through and understand the code. Still learning. :)

Comment: OK, I've added a full explanation for you at the bottom. I hope it is easy to understand. If you still need some clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The Date constructor also has a function called `getDay()` which returns a integer between 0 and 6 (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday). You can use this to detect Friday(0), Saturday(6), Sunday(0) and omit them.

Here is a demo that alerts you if it's the weekend:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2015);
myDate.setMonth(11);
myDate.setDate(6);

if(myDate.getDate() == 5 || myDate.getDay() == 6 || myDate.getDay() == 0) alert('Weekend!');

document.write(myDate);
```

To find the next day, pass the Date constructor a time & it will do the work for you. You will need to create an array however to format it in the way you want **November, 5 2015**.

**JS:**

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var tomDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var day = tomDate.getDate();
var month = monthNames[tomDate.getMonth()];
var year = tomDate.getFullYear()

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();


if(n == 5){
   var fromFri = n + 4;
   document.write("<b>" + month + " " + fromFri + ", " + year + "</b>");

}else if (n == 6){
   var fromSat = n + 3;
   document.write("<b>" + month + " " + fromSat + ", " + year + "</b>"); 

}else if (n == 0) {
   var fromSun = n + 2;
   document.write("<b>" + month + " " + fromSun + ", " + year + "</b>");

}else{
   document.write("<b>" + month + " " + day + ", " + year + "</b>");
}
```

Updated: [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/KdxaKV/)

Comment: I just checked, looks like the code does the job. But will the code show Monday's date on  every Friday, Saturday and Sunday ?

Comment: I fixed for you, it will alert you if it's the weekend, if not it will print the date!

Comment: Looks cool! Any way to integrate these two codes into one? The second code gives the right day, but it would be fantastic if it could show monday's date for Friday, Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: It would be best if the code could show just the Monday date for every friday, saturday and sunday without alert. Because I will put this code on my site, the alert message is not necessary.

Comment: yay i think i got it for ya! I was getting confused initially because we set up today's date + 1 for tomorrow. When I went to set up the condition statement I was using tomorrows date, I know I'm not that bad at math xP

Comment: In new as well and trying to learn, I appreciate corrections.

Comment: @icon No my friend. This solution does NOT work. Not for the last few days of each month.

Comment: Can you please show us where this goes wrong instead of whining?

Comment: The getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date, it's not that. Sunday being 0 and Saturday being 6. It's the first para of my answer, SO if you see something else let me know so I can look and make it better, thanks.

Comment: @Gothburz Well my fiend, you have so many errors in your code. It simply cannot be corrected. Yes, the `getDay()` will give you 0 to 6. And if it is 5 (Friday) for example, you add 4. Fair enough, so we give it "November 27, 2015" which is Friday and we get back "November 9, 2015". Do you see a problem there or you still need more explanation? And this is only one problem. You have at least 3 more issues, but there is no point in fixing them because the idea is wrong. You cannot add number to the day and expect the result to be a valid date.

Comment: Assuming I help you fix all those issues.. Assuming that instead of adding the 4 to the `getDay()`, we add it to `getDate()`... Now it will work for most days, but it will break for the last few days of some months. For example, you give it "October 30, 2015". It's Friday, so you try to add 4 to `getDate()` , but 30 + 4 = 34 and as you know there is no 34 days in October. The idea of adding numbers to the day is simply flawed. You need to add days to the date and JavaScript has a full library to calculate the answer, so to fix your code, we will have to rewrite a similar library.

Comment: Days of the week go from 0-6 bro.  getDay(), An integer between 0 and 6 representing the day of the week (Sunday is 0, Saturday is 6). It's never going to be add to October 30 lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94270/discussion-between-gothburz-and-racil-hilan).